# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01747

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jdbc

Searched through the entire site but nothing helped at all so I decided to open up a new topic. Here's my problem: I'm developing a simple GUI in java which uses JDBC behind the back. Here are some headlines:
- I established a successful database connection,
- I can run SELECT statements and fetch data within my code.
But the problem is that when I use an INSERT statement, It gives the error below which has a description like "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01747 invalid username.tablename.columnname or tablename.columnname etc..." 
I'm digging the web for 2 days but I couldn't come up with a solution to my need. Above is my code showing how I implemented the INSERT:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO DQMP.DQ_USER("
                                + " USER_ID,"
                                + " USER_SHORTNAME,"
                                + " USER_NAME,"
                                + " GSM1,"
                                + " E_MAIL,"
                                + " DEPARTMENT_ID,"
                                + ") VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";                             

                PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query);

                      st.setString(1, "user_id_seq.nextval");
                      st.setString(2, str1);
                      st.setString(3, str2);
                      st.setLong(4, lng);
                      st.setString(5, str4);
                      st.setInt(6, 1);

                      st.executeUpdate();
                      System.out.println("Insertion successful");
                      st.close();
```

Here's my DESC DQ_USER:

```
TABLE DQ_USER
 Name                                      Null?    Type                        
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 USER_ID                                   NOT NULL NUMBER                      
 USER_SHORTNAME                                     VARCHAR2(30)                
 USER_NAME                                          VARCHAR2(128)               
 GSM1                                               VARCHAR2(30)                
 E_MAIL                                             VARCHAR2(512)               
 DEPARTMENT_ID                             NOT NULL NUMBER
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code with latest changes:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                    String query = "SELECT USER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;";
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                    int seq = 0;
                    while(rs.next()){
                         seq = rs.getInt("USER_ID_SEQ");
                         System.out.println(seq);
                    }

                    CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call PKDQ_CONTROL_MNG.ADD_USER (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");

                    stmt.setInt(1, seq);
                    stmt.setString(2, str1);
                    stmt.setString(3, str2);
                    stmt.setInt(4, int1);
                    stmt.setString(5, str4);
                    stmt.setString(6, "1");

                    stmt.executeUpdate();
                    stmt.close();
```

Comment: Please DESC DQ_USER for reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a trailing comma in your insert statement. Remove it.

```
+ " DEPARTMENT_ID," // <-- Here is the trailing comma
+ ") VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Also, I guess that the USER_ID is of type NUMBER, and you try to store the String "user_id_seq.nextval" in this column.

If you want to insert the next value of a sequence, you must first issue a SQL query which selects the sequence next value, extract the number returned by this query, ans set it in your insert statement using `setInteger` or `setLong`.

Or you can just use the following query :

```
"INSERT INTO DQMP.DQ_USER(user_id_seq.nextval, 
+ " USER_SHORTNAME,"
+ ...
+ ") VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; // only 5 parameters
```

Comment: That's was good, I don't know how I missed that, thank you! But now it throws "ORA-01722: invalid number", May it be the LONG type I used?

Comment: LONG is an Oracle data type for storing character data of variable length up to 2 Gigabytes in length. It's not the equivalent of a Java long number. Use NUMBER to store Java longs.

Comment: well, I used int for the purpose because couldn't find a way to parse the actual NUMBER format, now I get the following:Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "04552100000"

Comment: This is another problem. Ask another question with the code you're using to parse the number.

Comment: Allright, I couldn't come up with anything new, so could you help me with that?

Comment: No. Not without seeing the code. Where is your other question?

Comment: I've written a procedure and named "add_user". I edit my post check that out.

Comment: Please ask another question. This is unrelated to your initial question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that's it, but your `INSERT` statement will end up looking like `INSERT INTO ... DEPARTMENT_ID,) VALUES(...`.

You've got a stray `,` after `DEPARTMENT_ID`.

Comment: thank you, helped a lot. But now I got "ORA-01722: Invalid number". Maybe the LONG type?